# Laravel Media Library Expected the file to have mimetype image/jpeg, but found a file with mimetype image/png

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I have a news aggregator site that grabs an image from a remote URL but the script is breaking with the following error when I try to crop the file after grabbing:

```
Expected the file at /home/vagrant/code/storage/media-library/temp/pemA8JMvkodnsavxgk5ZLXXHxeU3wo7n/tiny.jpg have mimetype image/jpeg, but found a file with mimetype image/png
```

I have no control over this image so I was wondering if there is a way to either correct the mimetype or to catch the error and remove the offending article?

Thanks in advance for your help

edit:
For clarity I am grabbing the image with:

```
$article->addMediaFromUrl($item['article']['image'])->toMediaCollection('article');
```

and then running:

```
$article->save();
```

The model has the following function:

```
public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void { 
   $this->addMediaConversion('listing')
      ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 140, 140)
      ->performOnCollections('article');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling with this in the future, I solved this with:

```
try {
     $article->save();
 } catch (InvalidTinyJpg $e) {
     echo "Skipped invalid file\n";
 }
```